# How to show silverlight in project type of visual studio 2008?

Tags: .net, silverlight

Previously Silverlight was not installed in my Visual Studio 2008. 
I have now installed the Silverlight 4.0 tool separately.

Now My problem is.

**I can't see any Silverlight project types in Visual Studio..**
pls guide me.

Comment: I think the Project Templates for Silverlight 4 are only available in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [Silverlight 3 Tools for Visual Stuido 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9442B0F2-7465-417A-88F3-5E7B5409E9DD&displaylang=en). Does this make a difference?

You're essentially looking for project templates I presume?

EDIT: You do need VS2010 in order to do Silverlight 4 projects though, BTW. You can, however, go get yourself a copy of the [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express) and develop in that.

Answer (score 0):

First you install "**Silverlight_4_Toolkit_April_2010**" and then install this "**Silverlight4_Tools**" after that you have to restart your system.

now open visualstudio2008 file new in that dialog window select `c#-->Silverlight->then shown one popup give ok open a new silverlight project`.

**Note**:During the installation of silverlight_4 show any sdk related errors. you must install "silverlight 4_sdk"